# Compile time guard for not calling not implemented functions

Tags: c++

i have a simple program:

```
int foo(int a){return a;}
double foo(double b){return b;}

int main(){
    foo(1);
    foo(1.0);
    /*some template guard to not call at all not implemented function*/ foo("bar");
    return 0;}
```

Can i write some template guard/macros, to not call or not compile not implemented/overloaded function?

Comment: Provide catch all overload? `template <typename... Ts> voif foo(Ts...) {}`

Comment: This will throw an error, I dont really understand your problem. If you dont want to reach this code at all, you have to implement some logic.

Comment: So you want `foo("bar")` to fail silently, with no effects? May I ask _why_?

Comment: @TomGebel I believe the question is... what _is_ that logic?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings In a large project i have complex template function: fill<T>(param, T),
this function should not be called at all, if T is a complex type, but still working with integers, doubles and some specific classes.. Weird case, i know

Comment: @НиколайСамородов Nah that makes sense. You might want to use `enable_if` and some type traits then, rather than listing all integer/float/double types. Up to you

Answer (score 0):

So, for this specific need i used:

```
template <typename T,std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value, int> = 0>
inline int foo(T ntc) {return -1;}
```

This overloads every wrong usage of my function, thx @AsteroidsWithWings